# Bootstrap Modal Popup with Linq & Every time clicked on triggered should go on Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq, popup, view

My Action in controller:

```
public ActionResult Profile1(string ID)
{
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var us = from u in db.Users
join s in db.Designations
on new { id = u.DesignationID } equals new { id = s.DesignationID }
where u.Id == ID
select new ViewEmployees
{
EmployeeCode = u.UserName,
EmployeeName = u.Name,
Father_Name = u.Father_Name,
DesignationName = s.DesignationName,
EmployeeType = u.EmployeeType,
Email = u.Email,
Mobile = u.Mobile
};
 return PartialView("Profile1", us);
}
```

My View whre i want to Show data in Modal popup...

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
 <td>
<a data-target ="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">@item.EmployeeName</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
@Html.Action("Profile1", "Attendance", new {id=item.EmployeeID })
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - AL-KHIDMAT FOUNDATION</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
}
```

when user click on Employee Name from List Of Employees 
It should show the profile of that employee whoose name is clicked...!

Comment: i want to get profile of an employee  in popup Modal when user click on Employee Name..
@GertArnold

Comment: Yes, you told that. But what's the problem?

Comment: It never shows the data..!!
just a transparent screen..! @Gert Arnold